# how can i select 1,4,7,10,13,... numbered records from table

Tags: sql

```
 ID NAME                        AGE     DEPTNO     SALARY
```

---

```
  1 shasank                      25         11       2025
  2 raju                         27         12       2027
  3 son                          33         12       2131
  6 bali                         31         10       2031
  4 don                          33         11       2132
  5 rambo                        32         11       2121
  7 dimpu                        33         12       2314
  8 chir                         34         10       2123
  9 nag                          35         10       2213
 10 ram                          28         13       2141
```

Comment: do you want _all rows where ids are defined by `1+(n-1)*3` for all integer n > 0_ ?

Comment: i want result without using id column

Comment: why? if this is homework please tag it as such...

Comment: what version of SQL are you using?

Comment: When you can tell us what SQL product you're using the  flag to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulo operator?  The `mod()` form is the standard way, but a lot of db's use the `%` operator too.

```
select * from table where MOD(ID,3) = 1;
```

Comment: thank u, and can u suugest me how can get result without using id  please.

Comment: As others have asked, you need to tell us what database you are using.  The particular row number of each result is available, but is database-implementation specific.  If you're trying to limit yourself to one-third of the data, why not just use a simple `limit N`, where `N` is one-third of the number of rows?  Unless you impose a sort on the table, selecting every third row is non-deterministic and (again) implementation-specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where id in (1,4,7,10,13)
```

Comment: ha ha, I am sure OP meant a arithmetic progression defined by `f(n) = 1 + (n-1)*3`

Comment: the questioner where told this formula?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: the ellipsis means that the series continues indefinitely. The series can be described by the formula I mentioned, which says, `id%3=1`

Comment: ellipsis is the three dots (...). It's used to show continuation. You can see in the question's title. So, an expression like `1,2,3,...,7` means `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and `1,2,3,...` means all positive integer. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ID % 3 = 1
```

Assuming, of course, that you are looking for every third ID.

Also, this is done with SQL Server - not sure what database you are using.

**EDIT**

Here is an option without using ID (SQL Server)

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) RowNum
      FROM table) X
WHERE X.RowNum % 3 = 1
```

Comment: thank u , and can u suggest me how can i get result without using id

Comment: sorry, you've lost me... you want to get records from the database based on the ID (presumably - the question doesn't state) but you don't want to use the ID to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT ..., ((@i := @i + 1) % 3) AS `i` FROM `table` ... HAVING `i` = 1
```